# How get a good result in a promise

Tags: javascript

My code :

```js
var sessionsActives = methodsSQL.getSessionsActives()

console.log(sessionsActives);
sessionsActives.then(function(result) {
   console.log(result.count);
});
```

Give that

```
Promise {<resolved>: {…}}
__proto__:Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]:Object
count:1
items:[{…}]
__proto__:Object
```

But ! `console.log(result.count)` return me `0` not `1`
Why ?

Edit :

```js
function getSessionsActives() {
    var db = new sqlite3.Database(pathDB)
    var exportData = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        db.serialize(function() {
            var query = "SELECT * FROM USERS"
            var i = 0
            var result = {
                count: 0,
                items: []
            }
            var person = {}
            db.each(query, function(err, row) {
                person = {user_firstname: row.user_firstname, user_lastname: row.user_lastname}
                i++
                result.count = i
                result.items.push(person)
            })
            db.close()
            resolve(result)
        })
    })
    return exportData
}
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: sessionsActives is not defined`

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: can you share sessionsActives definition?

Comment: Yes, just above it.

Comment: @PielSilbad they mean what are you setting `sessionActives` to, ie what is your `sessionsActive=...` assignment line

Comment: ok ok, I've updated ^^

Comment: Your updated code does nothing. It just defines a function that is never called.

Comment: I call the function above => var sessionsActives = methodsSQL.getSessionsActives()

Comment: your log results are not clear. you say "But ! console.log(result.count) return me 0 not 1 Why ?" but results are having `count:1`.

Comment: `ReferenceError: methodsSQL is not defined`

Comment: at the top of my file : const methodsSQL = require('./js/methods-sql.js')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve the promise in the db.each callback.

```
function getSessionsActives() {
var db = new sqlite3.Database(pathDB)
var exportData = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    db.serialize(function() {
        var query = "SELECT * FROM USERS"
        var i = 0
        var result = {
            count: 0,
            items: []
        }
        var person = {}
        db.each(query, function(err, row) {
            person = {user_firstname: row.user_firstname, user_lastname: row.user_lastname}
            i++
            result.count = i
            result.items.push(person)
            resolve(result)
        })
        db.close()

    })
})
return exportData
```

}

Comment: Okay it works, I don't understand why I didn't try this before... anyway thanks!

Comment: But a last question, if I want to put resolve(result) outside from db.each. How do I do it?

Comment: Yos have to call resolve after your asynchronous work is done which mean in the call back function of db.each. You can use async and await if db.each returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made this, it's cool. Thanks @Tarek

```js
            db.each(query, function(err, row) {
                person = {user_firstname: row.user_firstname, user_lastname: row.user_lastname}
                i++
                result.count = i
                result.items.push(person)

            }, function(err, count) {
                resolve(result)
                db.close();
            })
```